# Web development making buttons to change image and texts

Tags: html, css, image, button

I'm trying this code.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<img id="image1" src="img-170-intro-1.png" alt="intro1">
<script>
    function myFunction1() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
        document.getElementByID("image1").src = 'img-170-intro-1.png';
    }   
    function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Bye World";
        document.getElementByID("image1").src = 'img-170-intro-2.png';
    }
</script>
<button onclick="myFunction1()">Click me</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Click me</button>
```

and The texts are changing but the images aren't. How do I solve this?

Comment: Javascript is case-sensitive and you have getElementByID it should be getElementById

Answer (score 1):

Your document.getElementBy**ID** is incorrect, it needs to be document.getElementBy**Id** where you are setting the image src.

```
<script>
    function myFunction1() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
        document.getElementById("image1").src = 'img-170-intro-1.png'; //Here
    }   
    function myFunction2() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Bye World";
        document.getElementById("image1").src = 'img-170-intro-2.png'; //Here
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been struggling with this for so many hours.

Answer (score 0):

In both these lines :
`document.getElementByID("image1").src = 'img-170-intro-2.png';`
`document.getElementByID("image1").src = 'img-170-intro-2.png';`

just replace **getElementByID** with **getElementById** and your code is good to go. You just used a capital D instead of a small d in the function above. Also, these errors can be a big pain to spot with the bare eye, so I would suggest you to use a good code editor which will spot these kind of misses for you. You could use VScode, Webstorm or Eclipse.